# How to fit UIImageView around UIImage in UIStackView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get my UIImageView to fit around the UIImage.
This is what it should look like [image: good]

But this is what is happening [image: bad]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you explain in better detail what is wrong with the second image? I can't really tell what you're getting at. And what do you mean by "I am trying to get my UIImageView to fit around the UIImage"?

Comment: The first image has the rounded corners because the images bounds are actually that size, but the second image has all that space above and below it, I want auto layout to get rid of that.

Comment: You should make a uiimageview the same shape/size of the one above, and then set your image up to fit inside the frame. Should fix that.

Comment: It is set to aspect fit, but I want the intrinsicContentSize to reflect how large the image appears, but I guess it's calculating it based on how large the actually image is